# How do I differentiate arguments?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, args

So I want to have my code detect the different sections. The issue is it only thinks there is 1 argument. I tried some if statements and I console logged  it and it came out as 1. the code currently is:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'report',
    description: "report a naughty person",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client){ 
    const reason = args.splice(1)
    console.log (args)

if (args.length = 1){ 

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#1ed700')
        .setTitle('Report \n')
        .setDescription(`Person who reported ${message.author} \n`
        + `Channel reported in: ${message.channel}\n`
        + `Person reported: ${args[0]} \n` //The 1st argument
        + `Reason reported: ${reason.join(' ')}`) // The 2nd argument
         

    let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
    message.channel.send(`<@&${process.env.DUMMY_ROLE}>`)
    
} else
    message.channel.send('Code is not written properly')
    

}};
```

How would I be able to change it so that it comes out as 2 different arguments (the first 1 being the mention and the second being the reason). And how would I be able to check if there are these two arguments?

Comment: You're explicitly setting the length of `args` to 1 when splicing it with a single argument, and again in the `if` condition.

Comment: `args.length = 1` contains the assignment operator.

Comment: so @teemu should i remove the splicing, and if so how do i split it up?

Comment: If you want split it up, why are you expecting the length being bigger than 1? If you want to copy the values, you can use `slice`, `splice` with a single argument splits an array up to two parts, the one before the index in the argument, and the one starting from the index given in the argument to the end of the array.

Comment: @A-a-ron-ieYoutube Take a look at my answer. This should maybe help you. If not please comment below what's the issue

Comment: @GillesHeinesch your solution worked, sorry i stopped working for the day so i didn't see it till this morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you use an **assignment operator** to check if `args.length` is 1.
You want a **comparison** so what you want is the following:

```js
if (args.length === 1) {
// Do something
}
```

Try setting your args to the following code:

```js
const args = message.content.split(' ').slice(1); // Only use the last port slice() if you have a prefix like "-" or "+"
```

I added 2 checks to show you how you can check if a user has been mentioned and one other to check if the user has given a reason.
To check if there is a mention you can simply use `message.mentions.users.first();`. The only thing you forgot to add to the reason was `join(' ')` otherwise the user can just write one word as reason (I guess that's not what you wanted).

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'report',
    description: "report a naughty person",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client){ 
    const reason = args.splice(1).join(' ')
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();

   if (!user) return console.log('No user mentioned');
   if (!reason) return console.log('No reason given') // Checks if there is a reason given
   
   if (user && reason) {
  // Do something
console.log('User mentioned and reason given')
}
}};
```

Comment: The length will still be 1.

Comment: Why should it? @Teemu

Comment: Because of splicing the array when assigning a value to `reason`.

Comment: I don't get your point. If the user enters `?report @XX#0001 Test report` then the reason will be "Test report" and that's what the user wanted, is it? @teemu

Comment: They're checking the length of an array and getting unexpected results, we should focus on that, shouldn't we?

Comment: Do you agree now? I've added a new args which the user should redefine @Teemu

Comment: I'm not familiar with discord, and this probably does what OP needs, but it still only partially explains what went wrong in their own code ...

Comment: Yes that's true but we don't have the code which defines `args` so it's difficult to fix this one

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'report',
    description: "report a naughty person",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client){ 
    const reportedPerson = message.mentions.users.first();
    args.shift();
    const reason = args.join(' ');
    console.log(args);

    if(reportedPerson && reason){
      // Do something
    }
    else {
      console.log("No reported person or reason given!");
    }
    
};
```